# Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a bot on Dialogflow, and I am using Dialogflow-fulfillment. However I whenever I deploy, I receive the error:

```
Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail
```

I am trying to access an external API from the code. Is this the right way to do it? Or is the error due to some other reason?

P.S.: I am a newbie to Dialogflow.

Here is the index.js file:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const app =dialogflow();

function helper() {
   var username = '<USER_NAME>',
     password = '<PASSWORD>',
     sugar_id = '<SUGAR_ID>',
     from_date = '2019-06-10',
     to_date = '2019-06-11',
     url1 = '<SOME_URL_HERE>',
     auth = "Basic " + new Buffer.from(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    request(
         {
             url : url1,
             headers : {
                 "Authorization" : auth,
                 'x-api-key': '<API_KEY>',
                 'x-source': '<X_SOURCE>'
             }
         },
         (error, response, body) => {
             if(error) throw error;
            console.log('success 1');
             // console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
             var obj = JSON.parse(body);
             if(obj.data!==null) {
                 // console.log(obj.data[0].booking_id);
                 var latest_booking_id = obj.data[0].booking_id;
                 var url2 = '<SOME_URL_HERE>';

                 request(
                     {
                         url: url2,
                         headers : {
                             "Authorization" : auth,
                             'x-api-key': '<API_KEY>',
                             'x-source': '<X_SOURCE>'
                         }
                     },
                     (error, response, body) => {
                         if(error) throw error;
                       console.log('success 2');
                         var obj = JSON.parse(body);
                       if(error) reject(error);
                       console.log(obj);
                       resolve(obj);
                     }
                 );
             } else {
                 console.log('No booking found.');
             }

         }
     );

  });
}   

app.intent('customer details', (conv) => {
  helper().then((res)=> {
    conv.ask(res);
  }).catch((err)=> {
    throw (err);
  });
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.9.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might help: [Making an HTTP POST request from fulfillment in Dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555015/making-an-http-post-request-from-fulfillment-in-dialogflow).  To quote Prisoner's answer:

> The easiest way to use promises with network calls is to use a package
>   such as [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native). Using this, your code might look
>   something like:

```
var options = {
  uri: url,
  method: 'POST',
  json: true,
  headers: { ... }
};
return rp(options)
  .then( body => {
    var val = body.someParameter;
    var msg = `The value is ${val}`;
    agent.add( msg );
  });
```

I noticed that you're requiring the `actions-on-google` library. If you're building an action for the Google Assistant, reviewing [Google's codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0) for the Actions on Google client library might be helpful.